# Loadrunner Analysis Error

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner

I have created a script in virtual user generator, opened that script in controller and ran it. But the problem is that when I open Load Runner analysis for the results, it will display the error as below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen this before. But searching for the error string you see takes me to [this page](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/quot-Object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-quot/td-p/5851477) where they seem to have solved the issue. Please try that out.

It is a good habit to investigate on your own before you post questions.